# Blackberry - prevent deletion of app

Tags: blackberry, passwords

I made an app for parents to put on Their kids phones but need a way to protect against deletion. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no ways to do this short of installing a second app to monitor the first. Optionally you could have a web service that requires the app to phone-home at a predefined interval, but that quickly gets more complex than you were likely hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is deployed via a BES, you can use appropriate application control policies to prevent deletion.